# Android RecyclerView with PullRefreshLayout

Tags: android

I encountered some problems when I implemented today PullRefreshLayout (https://github.com/baoyongzhang/android-PullRefreshLayout ).
If I get down to the list and try to scrool back to the top the refresh triggers but it shouldn't untill I am not to the top of the list.

Is there any way to check the scrool position of the RecyclerView or any other method how to solve this glitch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to counter this, i used this in my fragment, mLinearLayoutManager is your recyclerview's layout manager:

```
public boolean isFirstItemCompletelyVisible() {
    return mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0;
}
```

And then:

```
@Override public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            mRefreshLayout.setEnabled(isFirstItemCompletelyVisible());
        }
    });
}
```

Plus:

```
mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && mRefreshLayout != null)
            mRefreshLayout.setEnabled(isFirstItemCompletelyVisible());
    }
});
```

What is basically does is disabling the refresh layout as long as we are not on the top of the list, having the first item fully visible